# Pass an array parameter to a C++ DLL from C#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling, dllimport

I am trying to pass an array of doubles to a function imported to C# from a C++ DLL.
The function looks like this in C++ DLL (calling convention cdecl is used):

`__declspec(dllexport) void FunctionToImport(void* values, size_t numberOfValues, const char* someString);`

Here the import in C#:

```
[DllImport("DLLToImport.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)] 
public static extern void FunctionToImport(IntPtr values, int numberOfValues, string someString);
```

When calling from C# this way:

```
double[] bytes = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 };

IntPtr testvalues = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytes.Length);
Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, testvalues, bytes.Length);

CSharpClass.FunctionToImport(testvalues, Marshal.SizeOf(testvalues), "someString";

Marshal.FreeHGlobal(testvalues);
```

I get an AccessViolationException, sometimes the program just crashes.

What would be a proper way to pass an array a size_t analog to the library?

Comment: First argument is IntPtr[].  What the array elements are supposed to point to, if anything, is completely unobvious.  Show some sample C/C++ code that uses this function to get the help you need.

Answer (score -1):

> I get an AccessViolationException, sometimes the program just crashes.

You get an exception because bytes.Length is 4, but you actually need to allocate 4*sizeof(double) bytes of memory.  You are confusing the number of elements in the array with the amount of memory you need to allocate.  Also, Marshal.Sizeof(values) is going to give you the size of the IntPtr whereas I think you need the count of elements.  Also, the C method signature makes this confusing: if it takes an array of doubles, why is the parameter void *[] instead of double[] or double *?  Your C# array is named "bytes" but it has doubles in it, which also leads me to question what the type the C code expects.  This void type doesn't jive with the second argument, which is "numberOfValues" since normally if something takes a void * it wants to know the number of bytes not the number of values.  So I think there is some lack of clarity around the API as well.

> [DllImport("DLLToImport.dll", CallingConvention =
> CallingConvention.Cdecl)]  public static extern void
> FunctionToImport(IntPtr values, int numberOfValues, string
> someString);
> This can work if you fixup the issues above so that you are allocating and copying the right amount of memory, but it is the hard way.  Instead, let P/Invoke do the Marshaling for you.  Try something like:

```
[DllImport("DLLToImport.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)] 
public static extern void FunctionToImport(double[] values, int numberOfValues, string someString);
```

This simplifies a lot.  Now you can call this method almost like a C# function:
doube

```
double[] numbers = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 };
FunctionToImport(numbers, numbers.Length, "someString");
```

There are times you need to use Marshal, but I suspect this is not one of them.

Comment: I think you overlooked that the C function accepts a double pointer (an array where each array element is a `void*`)